# Adding a "Select All" in drop down list

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, datasource

I have added a "Select All" value in ddlCategory to select all categories when it is selected but I got this error message "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String." Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```html
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ddlCategory.SelectedItem.Text == "Select All")
        {
            ProductDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT [ProductId], [ProductName], [ImageUrl], [Price], [CategoryId] FROM [Product] WHERE [SystemId] = 1";
        }
    }
```

Here is the code to ProductDataSource:

```html
<asp:SqlDataSource 
                   ID="ProductDataSource" 
                   EnableCaching="true" 
                   DataSourceMode="DataSet" 
                   runat="server" 
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString1 %>" 
                   SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductId], [ProductName], [ImageUrl], [Price], [CategoryId] FROM [Product] WHERE       [SystemId] = 1" 
                   FilterExpression="CategoryId = '{0}'">
            <FilterParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter Name="categoryparm" ControlID="ddlCategory" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Where did you get the error?

Comment: I cant see anything there will cause that error

Comment: Yeah there was no error in the code but when I ran it, that error message shows up. I'm guessing its the select statement? @shree.pat18

Comment: What is the data type of the SystemId column in the Product table?

Comment: I suggest you try debugging and stepping through your code to see which line throws the error.

Comment: the data type of the SystemId is int @Adish

Comment: You error must be somewhere else. What have you linked to ProductDataSource?

Comment: I just provided the code to ProductDataSource above @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: What is the datatype of CategoryID specified in Filter Expression of SqlDataSource?

Comment: the data type is int for CategoryId @Ramesh Babu 1

Comment: you have written `FilterExpression="CategoryId = '{0}'"` where {0} enclosed in single quotes. try it by removing single quotes for {0} as follows. `FilterExpression="CategoryId = {0}"`

Comment: It still didn't work, I was able to achieve what I needed by making FilterExpression = " " when select all is chosen. Thanks for the help @Ramesh Babu

Answer (score 0):

You added element *Select All*, but what is the value of your element? I think it is better to you to use *SelectedValue*. Add to your DropDownList element *Select All* with value 0, and then your method will looks like

```
if (ddlCategory.SelectedValue == 0){ /* your query here */}
```

Also I recommend you to perform this actions on first load of the page, not on postbacks. So your *Page_Load* method will looks like

```
if (!IsPostBack){
    if (ddlCategory.SelectedValue == 0)
        ProductDataSource.SelectCommand = "select * from product where systemid = 1";
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I get that error line under ddlCategory saying that Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int' @khazratbek

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue) == 0

Comment: @RonT try out this. Hope it helps

Comment: no luck yet. I wonder if it has to do something with the ProductDataSource. I just posted my code for it above. @Khazratbek